# Scroll up tableView when opening the keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have a UITable with some custom cells, on the last cell I have a `UITextField`, I want that all of the cells will scroll up when opening the keyboard (all kind of keyboards, with "Predictive" enabled and disabled).

I've looked at the other questions about this topic and tried but it still don't good enough (there is a gap between the cells to the keyboard, the animation of the tableView and the keyboard aren't synced, etc...).

Can you please help me with that?

Thank you!

Comment: check this. http://creativecoefficient.net/swift/keyboard-management/ ==> Theoretically only need change the `scrollView` for your `tableview`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the iOS Firechat example project on [Github](https://github.com/firebase/firechat-ios). It uses a textfield outside the tableView and moves the view along with the keyboard when it appears/disappears.

Specifically this section:

```
// Setup keyboard handlers to slide the view containing the table view and
// text field upwards when the keyboard shows, and downwards when it hides.
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [self moveView:[notification userInfo] up:YES];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [self moveView:[notification userInfo] up:NO];
}

- (void)moveView:(NSDictionary*)userInfo up:(BOOL)up
{
    CGRect keyboardEndFrame;
    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]
     getValue:&keyboardEndFrame];

    UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve;
    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey]
     getValue:&animationCurve];

    NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]
     getValue:&animationDuration];

    // Get the correct keyboard size to we slide the right amount.
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:animationCurve];

    CGRect keyboardFrame = [self.view convertRect:keyboardEndFrame toView:nil];
    int y = keyboardFrame.size.height * (up ? -1 : 1);
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, y);

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Here's the same in Swift, untested:

```
func moveView(userInfo : NSDictionary, up : Bool){

        var keyboardEndFrame : CGRect?
        userInfo.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey)?.getValue(&keyboardEndFrame)

        var animationCurve : UIViewAnimationCurve?
        userInfo.objectForKey(UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey)?.getValue(&animationCurve)

        var animationDuration : NSTimeInterval?
        userInfo.objectForKey(UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey)?.getValue(&animationDuration)

        UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
        UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
        UIView.setAnimationDuration(animationDuration!)
        UIView.setAnimationCurve(animationCurve!)

        let keyboardFrame = self.view.convertRect(keyboardEndFrame!, toView: nil)

        let y = keyboardFrame.size.height * (up ? -1 : 1);
        self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, y);

        UIView.commitAnimations()
    }
```

Comment: FS.O5 if you need in swift, so remove the objective-c tag in your question.